# CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error in preflight when fetching from Chrome Extension to SvelteKit endpoint

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors, sveltekit

When making a GET or POST request to a SvelteKit endpoint with an Authorization header, I get the error

```js
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/user' from origin 'chrome-extension://abcdefg' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have set `host_permissions` in my manifest (V3), `["https://*/*", "http://localhost:8000/*"]`.

In addition, my SvelteKit endpoints should be setting headers, possibly incorrectly,

```js
const res = new Response(JSON.stringify({ user }));
res.headers.set(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "chrome-extension://abcdefg"
    );
return res;
```

Not sure what else to try, as I need to send the Bearer token to my server, which triggers a preflight that seems to be the cause of this CORS error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `mode: 'cors',` to headers? Also, try `credentials: 'include',`

Comment: Sorry for the noice, I meant add `mode: 'cors'` and `credentials: 'include'` to the fetch request, not headers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`mode: 'cors'` in the client side fetch request fixed the problem. Thanks pulse!